# Call Gradlew from Procfile

Tags: gradle, heroku

I am trying to host a Gradle project on Heroku and run it by calling "gradlew.bat run" from the Procfile. Calling gradlew from the command line works perfectly. Calling it from the Procfile in the command line works perfectly, but for whatever reason calling the Procfile while deployed on Heroku itself returns this error immediately after launch:

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127 app[web.1]: bash: gradlew: command not found
```

Procfile:

```
web: gradlew run
```

The project is deployed over GitHub, and has autogenerated gradlew files

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

```
web: ./gradlew run
```

or, if gradlew is not executable

```
web: chmod a+x gradlew && ./gradlew run
```